# Own Delegate Method

Tags: iphone, delegates, touchesbegan

Good Morning Users,

i have implemented the follwing deleagate Method:

```
- (void)openFlowView:(AFOpenFlowView *)openFlowView doubleTapOnIndex:(int)index itemView:(AFItemView *)itemView{
    NSLog(@"Der Touch geht!!!!!");
}
```

And there the method should be prompted and called:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        if ([self.viewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(openFlowView:doubleTapOnIndex:itemView:)])
            [self.viewDelegate openFlowView:self doubleTapOnIndex:selectedCoverView.number itemView:selectedCoverView];
        }
    else {
```

But it never goes into the second if, does anybody know why that is so??

Greetings and thank you all for 
helping beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "self.viewDelegate" class is the class you have add the delegate method ?

Comment: Sorry i don't know what you mean, the class i have added the delegate method is the AFOpenFlowView.m

Comment: I think what Benoît is asking is whether a) the method openFlowView: etc. is declared in the class of your viewDelegate. Another possible problem could be that viewDelegate is nil if you have not yet set it at the time you are checking with respondsToSelector

Comment: You have these two methods in the same class (AFOpenFlowView) ?

Comment: @Joseph yes i think viewDelegate is nil because on Debugger it only shows 0x0, how could i solve this problem?

Comment: e.g. self.viewDelegate = THE OBJECT THAT IMPLEMENTS YOUR DELEGATE METHOD.

Comment: Marco : if your delegate method is in the same class, you just need to call method to self, not self.viewDelegate.

Comment: hmmm...it is very heavy to understand because i am new in objective C sorry!!

Comment: Joseph: how do you mean "the object that implements your delegate Method" sorry people

Comment: i have the problem self.viewDelegate is 0x0, how could i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include your method declaration in your header file?